# Create a UTC time zone object from a string

Tags: java, kotlin, timezone

I need a java.utils.TimeZone object that represents a UTC time zone (i.e. "UTC+4" in an object form). I tried the getTimeZone function, but it returns a GMT object.

```
val timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+4:00")
print(timeZone)
```

outputs

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

I have never worked with time zones and honestly I don't really understand them much, so if you could help me here that would be really appreciated

Comment: Do you _really_ need `java.util.TimeZone` or could you use the newer java.time API which would have something like `java.time.ZoneOffset`?

Comment: Yes I could do that, as long as it represents UTC time zones

Comment: Or use `java.time.ZoneId`: `ZoneId.of("UTC+04:00")`

Comment: Thanks, will try it right now

Comment: "as long as it represents UTC time zones" - That's what the Javadoc on `ZoneOffset` states: "A time-zone offset from _Greenwich/UTC_, such as +02:00. "

Comment: Instead of referring to "UTC time zones", it would be *much* clearer if you'd refer to "fixed-offset time zones". UTC means UTC and *only* UTC (and arguably isn't a time zone in itself, but that's splitting hairs). "UTC+4" is a time zone (sort of) that is "always four hours ahead of UTC".

Comment: If your string necessarily looks like that, `UTC+4:00`, you may define `OFFSET_FORMATTER` as `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() .appendLiteral("UTC") .appendOffset("+H:MM", "+0:00") .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)` and the get a `ZoneOffset` from `ZoneOffset.from(OFFSET_FORMATTER.parse("UTC+4:00"))` (yields `+04:00`).

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util` date-time API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

There is a difference between time zone and time zone offset. What you have mentioned is a time zone offset, not a time zone. A time zone is unique and therefore it has an ID e.g. `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")` whereas a time zone offset tells you about the amount of time by which a given time is offset from the UTC time. There can be many time zones falling on the same time zone offset. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones to learn more about it.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(instant);

        ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of("+04:00");
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(offset);
        System.out.println(odt);

        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-09-29T18:11:06.887943Z
2022-09-29T22:11:06.887943+04:00
2022-09-29T14:11:06.887943-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.